# Finding extensions of groups

Tags: group-theory

My understanding of a group extension is that the group $G$ extends the group $A$ by $B$ if there is a normal subgroup $N$ inside $G$ such that $N \cong A$ and $G/N \cong B$.

Now I am trying to find groups $G$ that extend $C_4$ by $C_2$ and also groups that extend $C_2$ by $C_4$. For the first one, I can spot that $G=C_8$ satisfies the conditions, but I have no idea to find any more extensions (if there are any) in general?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the two non-abelian groups of order $\;8\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, so $D_8$ and the quaternion group. I can see that the group generated by a rotation in $D_8$ is normal and isomorphic to $C_4$ and the quotient is isomorphic to $C_2$, but how do we know these are all the extensions? Does every extension have to be order 8? Thanks

Comment: Of course they have to be order 8 because $G/N = B$ so $|G| = |N||B|$!

Comment: Yes, of course....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have five groups of order $\;8\;$ up to isomorphism:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&C_8\;.\;\;\text{The cyclic one, both an extension of}\;\;C_2\;\;\text{by}\;\;C_4\;\text{and the other way around}\\{}\\\bullet&C_4\times C_2\;.\;\;\text{Same as above}\\{}\\\bullet&C_2\times C_2\times C_2\;.\;\;\text{An extension of}\;\;C_2\;\;\text{by}\;\;C_2\times C_2,\;\text{so none of the ones you're interested in}\\{}\\\bullet&Q_8\;.\;\;\text{All its proper subgroups are normal, yet}\;Q_8/C_2\cong C_2\times C_2\;,\;\text{so only an extension of}\; C_4\;\text{by}\;C_2\\{}\\\bullet&D_4\;.\;\;\text{Same as above}\end{align*}$$

In the last two cases (the non-abelian groups) , the center is of order two and thus isomorphic with $\;C_2\;$ , yet the quotient isn't $\;C_4\;$...and couldn't possibly be (why?)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it really makes it clear, I sometimes forget that we can actually list how many groups there are of small order. The reason why the quotient cannot be $C_4$ is because then there would be an element of order 4 and we don't have any?

Comment: Well, no @Wooster: both non-abelian groups have elements of order $\;4\;$ (the quaternion group has in fact six of them...). The problem is that in both cases the center of the group is of order two, and $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial.

Comment: Ah yes, I get it, thanks